How to enable logging for blpapi logs?
Currently I need to debug a market data subscription and I hope to obtain the blpapi logs to understand the transaction. Does anyone have an example to configure the logger and obtain blpapi logs during subscription?
I have looked up the Bloomberg api core developer guide and it only mentioned about setting blpapi log level to debug and a file directory to store all logs...

You can capture the logging messages within code, using a callback.
This is not very well documented (I had to look in the C++ header for the callback definition), but you can add this code, and register the callback (before you start the API Session):
import blpapi

def logCallback(threadId,severity,timeStamp,category,msg):
    #Do what you want with the information ...
    print(msg)

blpapi.Logger.registerCallback(logCallback,blpapi.Logger.SEVERITY_DEBUG)

If you first register the callback with SEVERITY_OFF you will get no messages. Then just before the code you want to debug you can call the function again with SEVERITY_DEBUG. In this way you will just get the messages for the actions you are interested in.
